# Disable a button from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Codepen is here: http://codepen.io/bwolfsohn/pen/jWVZwX

Trying to disable a button via jquery on submit.

I'm simulating an ajax response.

The button is not disabled, but the value on the button is changed to "disabled".

i've tried:

```
($d).button('disable');
($d).prop( "disabled", true );
```

where am i going wrong ??

html:

```
<form class="form-inline bidding" id="rbconfirm" name="IamBidding" action="#">
<input id="arBidAmount_7101" type="text"  name="aBidAmount_7101" value="450.00">  
<input id="rbbutton" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Bid Now">
```

jquery/js

```
$(function () {

var obj2 = {
"arBidAmount_7101" : {
"value" : "500.00"
},
"rbbutton" : {
"disable" : "disabled"
}
};
$("#rbconfirm").submit(function(e){
 $.each(obj2, function(i, item) {
        var d = i;
        var $d = $('#' + i);
        if ($d.length !== 0) {
   $.each(item,function(i,item) {
      if ($d.is(':input')) {
        ($d).val(item);
       }
      else if (i=='disable') {
        ($d).prop( "disabled", true );
       }
      else if (i=='value') {
      ($d)[0].innerHTML = item;
      }
    else{
      if (typeof console == "object") {
        console.log('notinput '+ i + d);
       }
      }
    });
        } else {
        if (typeof console == "object") {
              console.log(i + 'notfound');
          }
        }
      });
     e.preventDefault();
     });
  });
```

Here is the corrected javascript... 
thanks to @pranin-shakya for the key to the problem..

```
changing this line:
if ($d.is(':input')) {

to this line:
if (($d.is(':input')) && (!$d.is(':submit')))
```

to exclude the submit button from being evaluated as an input.

```
$(function () {

var obj2 = {
"arBidAmount_7101" : {
"value" : "500.00"
},
"rbbutton" : {
"disable" : "true"
}
};
$("#rbconfirm").submit(function(e){
  console.log(obj2);
 $.each(obj2, function(i, item) {
        var d = i;
        var $d = $('#' + i);
        if ($d.length !== 0) {
   $.each(item,function(i,item) {
      if (($d.is(':input')) && (!$d.is(':submit')))
      {
        ($d).val(item);
       }
      else if (i=='disable') {
        $($d).prop( "disabled", true );
       }
      else if (i=='value') {
      ($d)[0].innerHTML = item;
      }
    else{
      if (typeof console == "object") {
        console.log('notinput '+ i + d);
       }
      }
    });
        } else {
        if (typeof console == "object") {
              console.log(i + 'notfound');
          }
        }
      });
     e.preventDefault();
     });
  });
```

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, both  $($d).prop( "disabled", true ); and $d.prop( "disabled", true ); still change the value to disable, but do not disable the button..

Comment: sorry my bad .. I'm working on that

Comment: if i change the element in obj2 to:
'"rbbutton" : {
"disable" : "true"
}' , the button is changed to true. so it's reading the word disable, but executing it as == 'value'

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, it looks like the problem is on the line:
'if ($d.is(':input'))'. the button is an input, so it's executing that for both... how can i change that line so it only executed on actual inputs and excludes buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
  if ($d.is(':input')) {
    ($d).val(item);
     if (i=='disable') {
    $($d).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
   }
   }
```

Your code is not functioning properly as your logic contradicts on line

--if ($d.is(':input')) {--

Since the submit button is also of type INPUT it will return true, the else statement you included

--($d).prop( "disabled", true )-- IS NEVER EXECUTED.

Comment: that's correct... but, this is part of a larger if else statement... the question now is how can i change the single line    'if ($d.is(':input'))' to exclude the button..

Comment: your idea would still change the value of the button to "disabled" or "true"

Comment: You could use something like if($d.is(':submit')==false){} to exclude only the submit button. REFERENCE : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_input_submit.asp

Answer (score 0):

### Basic Concept

**You can do This whitch is preety basic:**

```
$("some sort of selector").prop("disabled", true | false);
```

**If you are using a jQuery UI styled button then it should be enabled / disabled via:**

```
$("some sort of selector").button("enable" | "disable");
```

Learn more [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-disable)!

### So implementing that in your code:

```
($d).button('disable');
```

**You can do this:**

```
($d).prop("disabled", true);
```

**Or:**

```
($d).button('disable');
```

### Here is an example

Here is a good code example from stackoverflow!:

```js
$('.rbutton').on('click',function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled",true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="rbutton">Click me</button>
```

Comment: it's a bootstrap button, and i am doing ($d).prop( "disabled", true );

Comment: @BrianWolfsohn I edited my anwser at bottom using snippet. Does that help?

Comment: no... see my comment on the question... the problem is on the line:       'if ($d.is(':input'))'

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if/else` statement for `i`  after check `is(:input)`

```
 if ($d.is(':input')) {
    $($d).val(item);

   if (i=='disable') {
    console.log(d);
    console.log($d);
    // ($d).button('disable');
    $d.prop( "disabled", true );
   }
   if (i=='value') {
   //console.log($d);
   // console.log( ($d)[0].innerHTML );
  $($d)[0].innerHTML = item;
  // console.log( ($d)[0].innerHTML );
  }
}else{
  if (typeof console == "object") {
    console.log('notinput '+ i + d);
  }
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMoyyE)

> > **Note:** you need to work around if/else statements to use it right up to your need

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function addClass.() in jquery (if you use bootstrap)

$("#yourButton").addClass("disable");